# Unable to Login For Yahoo Using oAuth in Android

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, yahoo

Hi @ll i am using **oAuth Library** to do several App `Login Authentication` 
i.e{ Facebbok, GooglePlus, Yahoo } in Android App.
**Facebook** & **GooglePlus** is Working Like Charm, But the Problem i am facing is in **Yahoo App** while i also Configured the App on Yahoo.So i have  **CONSUMER_KEY** , **CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY**,**APPLICATION_URL**,**CALLBACK_URL**,**APP_ID**. But Still I am getting the below Error Message as shown in image While Login.I Don't Know What is the Cause of this.Any help will be Appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You need to add the code, only then I will be able to help. This screen doesn't help in anyway. However, the error message is not good as placeholder "{0}" is not replaced with the actual issue description.

Comment: hi @ripudam, thnx for your response. i am using this demo `http://socialauth-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/socialauth-android/` so i have same code as of in this link & only im changing & setting Authenticating params.